# MVC EF Adding object to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, orm

So this is a continuation of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062540/entityframework-creating-many-to-many-relationships-automatically/37062598?noredirect=1#comment61672305_37062598)

I am trying this below:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Sport> Sports { get; set; }
public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

- I can have many Sports
- I can have many Teams in a Sport
- I can have many Teams in a User
- I can have many Users in a Team

**Sport**

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

**Team**

```
public Team(int ID, int SportID, int Wins, int Losses, String Name, String Description, double Reputation, List<User> Members, byte[] TeamLogo)
 {
     this.ID = ID;
     this.SportID = SportID;
     this.Wins = Wins;
     this.Losses = Losses;
     this.Name = Name;
     this.Description = Description;
     this.Reputation = Reputation;
     this.Members = Members;
     this.TeamLogo = TeamLogo;
 }
public int ID { get; set; }
public List<User> Members { get; set; }
public int SportID { get; set; }
```

**User**

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

**DB**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Adds middle table between Users and Teams
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<Team>(t => t.Teams)
            .WithMany(m => m.Members)
            .Map(w => w.ToTable("UserTeam")
                       .MapLeftKey("UserID")
                       .MapRightKey("TeamID"));
    }

public void addTeam(Team team, String sport)
    {
        // Add the team to the correct sport
        Teams.Add(team);
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
model.NewTeam = new Team(0, db.getSportID(model.SelectedSport), 0, 0, model.TeamName, model.TeamDescription,
                   100, new List<User>() { model.currentUser }, model.ActualImage);
db.addTeam(model.NewTeam, model.SelectedSport);
```

Issue:

It adds a record to the Teams table just fine. It adds the record to the UserTeam table just fine. The problem is that it is also adding a new record to the User table as well so I have repeating users in my User table. Also, when I query the Teams Table, I get a null List Members so EF isn't properly getting the Members of each team from the Many-Many table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue came from this code :

```
public void addTeam(Team team, String sport)
{
    // Add the team to the correct sport
    Teams.Add(team);
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

The line `Teams.Add(team)` will browse the `team` instance, all navigational properties, each item in each navigational collections and mark them as there are new entries. It means each entry will have its state equlas `EntityState.Added`. Then when you call `this.SaveChanges()` it will create new line into your database for each entry that has `EntityState.Added` state.

To fix your issue you need to make sure that context that you use to save your data is the same that you use to retrieve the items that you use in the following list `new List<User>() { model.currentUser }`

If your contexts aren't the same then on `addTeam` method you need to change the state of each `User` and mark them as `EntityState.Unchanged` so the context will not add them as newly created entry like this:

```
public void addTeam(Team team, String sport)
{
    // Add the team to the correct sport
    Teams.Add(team);
    foreach(var user in team.Users)
    {
        this.Entry(user).EntityState = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is exactly what you said. The new List<User>() was not the context from the database so it was creating a new User object in the database. A simple select where my current user was fixed it. Thanks!